# how to use VLOOKUP in google spreadsheet and microsoft excel

Tags: google-sheets-formula, vlookup

What are the different ways to use Vlookup functions and understand it simply. How to lookup data from two different workbook

I could not understand the function to use

Comment: Maybe you should check the function filter un GSS

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.